# "Pulling" parameters from a job in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

After searching around online for answers, I am still having trouble on how I can do this.

I currently have a job that triggers other jobs and proceeds after those other jobs are successful (job C triggers job A and B). All jobs are multibranch pipeline jobs and I want to be able to get the git hashes of job A and job B (different hashes), so that I can use them in job C.

I know if it was just two jobs, I could pass down parameters from one job and trigger the build, but I was wondering if there is a way for a job to "pull" parameters from multiple jobs that it triggered.

Perhaps, if there is a way, instead of job C triggering the build of job A and job B, I could start by building job A and B separately, and pass down the git hashes to job C, and only trigger the build of job C if both A and B are successful?

Sorry if this is worded terribly, I am still very new to Jenkins. Thank you in advance for any help!